# Хешировать в SHA512 без гемороя в jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, хеширование

Можно ли получить `SHA512` хеш строки в jQuery без огромных функции, циклов и прочего. Например мне надо хешировать строку:

```css
input {width: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="password" placeholder="ВВЕДИТЕ ЧТО-НИБУДЬ"/><button id="act">Конвертнуть</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" disabled id="hashOutput" placeholder="SHA512 хеш введенной строки"/>
```

введенную в первое поле при нажатии кнопки `Конвертнуть`. Как это сделать максимально просто и логично?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите библиотеку [jsSHA](https://github.com/Caligatio/jsSHA) добавив библиотеку в проект

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/sha.js"></script>
```

через `cdn`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/2.2.0/sha512.js"></script>
```

или установите через `npm`

```
npm install jssha
jsSHA = require("jssha");
```

а потом вызовите

```
var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
shaObj.update("This is a ");
shaObj.update("test");
var hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
```

```js
var shaObj = new jsSHA("SHA-512", "TEXT");
shaObj.update("This is a ");
shaObj.update("test");
var hash = shaObj.getHash("HEX");
$("#res").text(hash);
```

```html
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsSHA/2.2.0/sha.js"></script>

<body>
 <div id="res"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: jsSHA is not deifned

Comment: Скорее всего вы подключили библиотеку после того, как воспользовались ей

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться нативной функцией JavaScript из [SubtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto):

```js
text.onkeyup = function()
{
  let str = text.value;
  let str_bytes = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
  
  let hash_promise = crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-512", str_bytes);

  hash_promise.then(function(hash_buffer)
  {
    let hash_bytes = new Uint8Array(hash_buffer);
    
    let hash_hex = Array.prototype.map.call(hash_bytes, x => ("00" + x.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
    
    result.innerText = hash_hex;
  });
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="text" type="text" placeholder="Текст для хеширования">
</form>

<br>

<div id="result"></div>
```

[Поддержка браузерами](https://caniuse.com/?search=SubtleCrypto)